# Font Awesome 5 Is there a non-breakable space for "fa-layers-text" class?

Tags: font-awesome, whitespace, font-awesome-5

I'm really stuck at this supposedly easy task: I'd like to put one single line of text containing white spaces over an FA icon. Following [their instructions](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/styling/layering) works only as long as the text does not contain any blanks. Blanks wrap the text into the next line. How can I prevent this so that there's only one single line of text (no matter how wide) put over an icon?

This creates three lines of text over the solid heart icon - I'd like just one.

```css
.fa-layers {
  margin:50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.12.0/js/all.js"></script>
<span class="fa-layers fa-fw">
 <i class="fas fa-heart" data-fa-transform="grow-96" style="color:red"></i>
 <span class="fa-layers-text" style="font-weight:900">any text here</span>
</span>
```

Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply consider `white-space:nowrap;`

```css
.fa-layers {
  margin:50px;
}
.fa-layers-text {
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.12.0/js/all.js"></script>
<span class="fa-layers fa-fw">
 <i class="fas fa-heart" data-fa-transform="grow-96" style="color:red"></i>
 <span class="fa-layers-text" style="font-weight:900">any text here</span>
</span>
```

Comment: So it really is that easy. Shame on me and thank you very much.